# pl sql dml Trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

```
:NEW.eqv_turnover_all_credit  ', ' 

                'curr_oper_code = '  ''''  :NEW.curr_oper_code  ''''  ', ' 

                'curr_oper_subcode = '  '''' 

                :NEW.curr_oper_subcode  ''''  ', ' 

                'mcc_param_type = '  ''''  :NEW.mcc_param_type  ''''  ', ' 

                'ips_param_type = '  ''''  :NEW.ips_param_type  ''''  ', ' 

                'mt_param_type = '  ''''  :NEW.mt_param_type  ''''  ', ' 

                'msfo = '  ''''  :NEW.msfo  ''''  ', ' 

                'display_name = '  ''''  :NEW.display_name  ''''  ', ' 

                'client_uid = '  :NEW.client_uid  ', ' 

                'external_product_id = '  '''' 

                :NEW.external_product_id  ''''  ', ' 

                'external_product_code = ' 

                :NEW.external_product_code  ', '  'group_set = ' 

                :NEW.group_set  ', '  'category_set = ' 

                :NEW.category_set  ', '  'security_level = ' 

                :NEW.security_level  ', '  'branch_id = ' 

                :NEW.branch_id  ', '  'cross_acc_id = ' 

                :NEW.cross_acc_id  ', '  'cross_code_filial = '  '''' 

                :NEW.cross_code_filial  ''''  ', '  'deal_id = ' 

                :NEW.deal_id  ', '  'sb_code = '  '''' 

                :NEW.sb_code  ''''  ' WHERE id = '  :OLD.id;



WHEN DELETING THEN

  v_sql_text := 'DELETE FROM accounts WHERE id = '  :OLD.id;

   

  END CASE;



  insert into iabs_scan

(osuser,

 machine,

 programm,

 ip_address,

 start_time,

 sql_text,

 complete_time,

 table_name)



 values

(v_osuser,

 v_machine,

 v_program,

 v_ip_address,

 v_start_time,

 v_sql_text,

 v_complete_time,

 v_table_name);

 



END;
```

it is compiled succesfully . on my pc it all right  but if i do some dml operations on accounts table  on another pc's  delete and insert parts are working but update part of the trigger does not work at all it stays just showing executing.

here is a picture .

And give some  advice about to take sql_text of insert, delete , update that is more easier than mine

like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC21Q.jpg)

i have tried on several pc's

Comment: I doubt it compiled successfully; at least, not if code really looks as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that another session updated row in `accounts` table whose `id = 2079744` and didn't `commit` (nor `rollback`), so your session has to wait until that happens.

Therefore, find the one who did it and tell them to perform one of these two actions (commit or rollback).

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot it works . Do i have to commit after each update?

Comment: Eventually. If you're satisfied with outcome of the UPDATE statement, then COMMIT. Otherwise, Oracle lets you change your mind and ROLLBACK so that you could start over (of abandon the idea of updating). But, until you do one of these, other sessions will find affected rows LOCKED.